# python datetime with 6 digit milliseconds

Tags: python, python-3.x

How could I print 6 digit milli seconds in below format

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now(tz = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo).isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')
'2022-01-10T18:29:10.698000+05:30'
```

Actual Output:

```
 '2022-01-10T18:29:10.108+05:30'
```

Expecting Output something like:

```
  '2022-01-10T18:29:10.108000+05:30'
```

Comment: There are only 1000ms in 1 second

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `timespec=microseconds`:

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now(tz = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo).isoformat(timespec='microseconds')
'2022-01-10T14:05:55.742931+01:00'
```

**Update**:

If you want 0 for microsecond value, you can do:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone()
now = now.replace(microsecond=now.microsecond // 1000 * 1000)
now = now.isoformat(timespec='microseconds')
print(now)

# Output
'2022-01-10T14:17:08.386000+01:00'
```

Answer (score 2):

There are only 1000ms in 1 second, do you mean `microseconds`?

```
datetime.datetime.now(tz = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo).isoformat(timespec='microseconds')
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want utc and milliseconds value, you can do**

**UTC Convertion**

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
epoch: datetime = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
print(epoch)
```